# What do you call a ticket/pass for several sightseeing attractions?

Tags: single-word-requests

Assume you are traveling in a place, and there may be several tourist attractions. And you'd like to buy a ticket that can be used for several sites and is usually cheaper than if you buy every single ticket for every single site. Do you have a word for that ticket such as an all-mighty ticket or whatever I guess?

Comment: There are actual names for them by the companies that market them, like there is the London Pass in London or maybe a super pass or a disney pass. However I think the generic term is 'pass' itself, the qualifier comes from the marketeer.

Comment: Just an FYI 'How do you call' isn't how English first language speakers would phrase the question, it would more usually be 'What do you call...'.

Comment: In the US such a thing is generally referred as a "pass".  Though terms such as "combination ticket" are also used.  ("Pass" refers to any ticket-like thing which is good for more than one admission.)

Answer (score 4):

It is often called a **combination ticket** (or 'combo ticket') in many countries.

(About [71,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?search?&q=%22combination%20ticket%22) by Google)

Answer (score 3):

You could call it an [all-in-one](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+all+in+one) ticket:

> combining two or more items or functions in a single unit.
>
> *"an all-in-one shampoo/conditioner"*

Similarly, you could also call it an [all-inclusive](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20all%20inclusive) ticket:

> including everything or everyone.
>
> *"the tab for the all-inclusive dinner is $38"*

There really isn't a single word that describes these, as it's going to depend more on the city you're in, the tour company you're using, etc. But I think most people would know what you meant with either of the above options, depending on the context you use them in.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities: 'multi-site pass/ticket', 'universal pass/ticket' and 'all-in ticket'. I think the latter has a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that a word **multipass** would left you be understood in most non-english-speaking-tourist-attractive places.

I am speaking of an idea that what you need is to say that you are interested in a combined product that is otherwise available as a collection of separate purchases and you are interested in a discount.

Speaking of a ticket that gives more than one access to the same product or service might be different.

For instance when I apply for a visa in order to visit the schengen zone I ask for either a `single time visa` or a `multivisa` depending on the circumstances.